# MBP with Touchbar install Debian 10 fails

Tags: unix, dual-boot

Trying to create a dual boot system with Debian 10 on my MBP 2016 but the installation process fails because the keyboard input is not recognized. I can move through the initial menu where I can select what I want to do

- Graphical installation
- Installation
  ...

but I can not move through the followup installation where in the first step I shall select a language.

Wrong linux?
Need to use a specific version with specific driver pack? 
Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debian 10 comes with Kernel version [4.19](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianBuster).  According to [State of Linux on the MacBook Pro 2016 & 2017](https://github.com/Dunedan/mbp-2016-linux)

> **Keyboard & Touchpad**
>
> `MacBookPro13,1 working` `MacBookPro13,2 working` `MacBookPro13,3 working` `MacBookPro14,1 working` `MacBookPro14,2 working` `MacBookPro14,3 working`
>
> Works out of the box with Linux 5.3 and above.
>
> For earlier Linux versions you can get the driver from https://github.com/roadrunner2/macbook12-spi-driver.

Therefore you need either the patch or a distro with a more recent kernel (for example Arch Linux - the [current iso](https://www.archlinux.org/download/) has 5.3.1 kernel - or from next month [Ubuntu 19.10](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/09/linux-5-3-kernel-release-features)).

If you want to use Debian 10 you should be able to install using external keyboard and then install the spi driver as described in the link above.